# Trying to subtract below cell value from above cell value while top row is being added from macro

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to subtract below cell value from above cell value and store the result to monitor the value change every 3 mins via macro, getting an error, can someone help me get a fix here.

getting runtime error 1004, Application defined or object defined error at line

```
ws2.Cells(newRow2, "T").Value = ws2.Cells(newRow2, "S4").Value - ws2.Cells(newRow2, "S3").Value
```

Code Snipped below

```
Dim ContinueLogging As Boolean ' Global variable to control logging

Sub RecordOpenInterestData()
    If ContinueLogging Then
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim newRow As Long
        Dim ws2 As Worksheet
        Dim newRow2 As Long
        
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FYRNIFTY")
        Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OIData")
        
        newRow = 33
        newRow2 = 3

        ws.Rows(newRow).Insert
        ws2.Rows(newRow2).Insert
        
        ws.Rows(newRow + 1).Copy ws.Rows(newRow)
        ws2.Rows(newRow2 + 1).Copy ws2.Rows(newRow2)
        
        ws.Rows(newRow).ClearContents
        ws2.Rows(newRow2).ClearContents
        
        ws.Cells(newRow, "A").Value = Now()
        ws2.Cells(newRow2, "A").Value = Now()
        
        ws2.Cells(newRow2, "B").Value = ws.Range("B13").Value
        ws2.Cells(newRow2, "C").Value = ws.Range("L13").Value
        ws2.Cells(newRow2, "D").Value = ws.Range("B14").Value
        ws2.Cells(newRow2, "E").Value = ws.Range("L14").Value
        ws2.Cells(newRow2, "F").Value = ws.Range("B15").Value
        ws2.Cells(newRow2, "G").Value = ws.Range("L15").Value
        ws2.Cells(newRow2, "H").Value = ws.Range("B16").Value
        ws2.Cells(newRow2, "I").Value = ws.Range("L16").Value
        ws2.Cells(newRow2, "J").Value = ws.Range("B17").Value
        ws2.Cells(newRow2, "K").Value = ws.Range("L17").Value
        ws2.Cells(newRow2, "L").Value = ws.Range("B18").Value
        ws2.Cells(newRow2, "M").Value = ws.Range("L18").Value
        ws2.Cells(newRow2, "N").Value = ws.Range("B19").Value
        ws2.Cells(newRow2, "O").Value = ws.Range("L19").Value
        
        ws2.Cells(newRow2, "Q").Value = ws2.Cells(newRow2, "H").Value + ws2.Cells(newRow2, "J").Value + ws2.Cells(newRow2, "L").Value
        ws2.Cells(newRow2, "R").Value = ws2.Cells(newRow2, "I").Value + ws2.Cells(newRow2, "K").Value + ws2.Cells(newRow2, "M").Value
        ws2.Cells(newRow2, "S").Value = ws2.Cells(newRow2, "R").Value - ws2.Cells(newRow2, "Q").Value
        ws2.Cells(newRow2, "T").Value = ws2.Cells(newRow2, "S4").Value - ws2.Cells(newRow2, "S3").Value
                
        ws.Cells(newRow, "B").Value = ws2.Range("Q3").Value
        ws.Cells(newRow, "C").Value = ws2.Range("R3").Value
        ws.Cells(newRow, "D").Value = ws2.Range("S3").Value

        Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:02:59"), "RecordOpenInterestData"
    End If
End Sub

Sub StartLogging()
    ' Set the flag to allow logging
    ContinueLogging = True
    ' Call the LogValuesEvery30Seconds macro
    RecordOpenInterestData
End Sub

Sub StopLogging()
    ' Set the flag to stop logging
    ContinueLogging = False
End Sub
```

Comment: `ws2.Cells(newRow2, "S4")` should be `ws2.Cells(newRow2, "S")` - same for the other cells

Comment: `Cells(newRow2, "S3")` makes no sense and is invalid. The second parameter to `Cells` is for the column and is either a number (eg `3`) or a column character (eg `"S"` or `"AA"`)

Comment: Did that already as suggested, what i want is  that as the rows are getting filled I want the 2nd recent record from Column S to minus the most recent record from Column S which always will be S4-S3 and save in T column. Could u pls suggest how can I get around this.

Comment: `ws.Range("S4").value - ws.range("S3").value`?

Comment: Will try that and update here.